# What could create block in that case when 'blocking' procedure/spid not do any select / almost nothing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, blocking

I had situation like this today- sorry that this is screenshot but it is easier way to show what i need to understand

[image]

As on screen - many processes was blocked by `SPID 91`

This `SPID 91` querry was as on screen botom - procedure with name 'sprawdz_zlecenia_1'

But body of this procedure 'sprawdz_zlecenia_1' was /is like this now

```sql
select 0 as Liczba
```

Nohing more, so please let me known what am I missing here.

How this procedure that does not do any select even could create this block on server?

Comment: Check for open transactions, could be multiple statements in a transaction, you're only seeing the last one.

Comment: thanks i will check when next time will happen

Answer (score 1):

### buttery

You'd probably find [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) a better source of information that any of the built-in `sp_who` procedures.

Here's an example command that will order the output by which sessions have the most blocked sessions under them.

It will also add a column called `additional_info` to the output, which has XML details on which locked object blocked queries are waiting to access.

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive 
    @get_task_info = 2, 
    @get_additional_info = 1, 
    @find_block_leaders = 1, 
    @sort_order = '[blocked_session_count] DESC';
```